# *ngIf inside *ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I am checking the status if the employee is present or absent. If he is present then display a green badge saying present else display red batch with absent.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of attendance; let i = index">
    <th>{{i + 1}}</th>
    <td>{{item.empid}}</td>
    <td>{{item.first_name}} {{item.last_name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.date | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="{{item.status}} == 'present'">
        <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-success">Present</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am tried using ng-template it is not working. I tied solving on my own i couldnt i need some help.

Comment: You don't need the curly braces in `*ngIf`. `*ngIf="item.status == 'present'"`

Comment: You are using wrong syntax, check out the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#description) for the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the {{}} syntax inside of HTML tags. Try:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of attendance; let i = index">
    <th>{{i + 1}}</th>
    <td>{{item.empid}}</td>
    <td>{{item.first_name}} {{item.last_name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.date | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="item.status === 'present'">
        <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-success">Present</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

curly braces are not necessary. modify your code as below.
replace `<td *ngIf="{{item.status}} == 'present'">` with  `<td *ngIf="item.status === 'present'">`

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of attendance; let i = index">
     <th>{{i + 1}}</th>
     <td>{{item.empid}}</td>
     <td>{{item.first_name}} {{item.last_name}}</td>
     <td>{{item.date | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
     <td *ngIf="item.status === 'present'">
         <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-success">Present</span>
     </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: another thing I've noticed is, you have used == to check the equality, The == operator compares the value after applying the type coercion, if applicable. The === operator compares the value without applying the type coercion. For example, 1 == "1" evaluates to true, but 1 === "1" evaluates to false.
since you clearly know item.status is a string, use === instead of ===